# Using stored procedures with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, stored-procedures, sp-executesql

I want to use LINQ to call stored procedure in [this way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2007/10/25/linq-and-stored-procedures.aspx) but stored procedure I want to call contain SQL string that executed by

```
EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL
```

In this way Visual Studio does not generate result class. To resolve this problem I execute SQL string by

```
INSERT INTO @Temp EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL
SELECT * from @Temp
```

Maybe it is not the best way but it works. The problem is that it sometimes return items in wrong sequence. How to fix it?

Comment: Why do you use sp_executesql ?

Comment: This question scares me.

Comment: not the end of the world if only used in a local setting

Comment: @BasB I don't know a reason. This is a little bit complicated query (written not by me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [Order By](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx) to specify the sort order

Comment: Thanks. I just moved Order By line from SQL string to final SELECT and it did the trick.